# Maximum number of columns in Google BigTable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bigtable

I found documentation for the maximum number of columns in BigQuery (10K) but I can't seem to find that information for BigTable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Cloud BigTable Quota & Limits documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/quotas#limits) has a section about [data size limits within tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/quotas#limits-data-size):

> As a best practice, [design your schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design) to keep the size of your data below these recommended limits:
>
> - A single row key: 4 KB
> - Column families per table: 100
> - A single column qualifier: 16 KB
> - A single value in a table cell: 10 MB
> - All values in a single row: 100 MB
>
> In addition, you must ensure that your data fits within these hard limits:
>
> - A single value in a table cell: 100 MB
> - All values in a single row: 256 MB

In BigTable, the data within tables tends to be limited by size of the data instead of by number of columns or rows (except for "Column families per table").

On another note, there's a [maximum of tables that a Cloud BigTable instance supports](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/quotas#limits-tables-per-instance), it's 1.000 tables.